# PayPal IOS SDK: Request has failed with error: UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT - The merchant does not accept payments of this type. (401)

Tags: objective-c, paypal

I need help! Error message appear when I try to make to payment using iOS paypal sdk.(live or sandbox mode).

> PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT - The
>   merchant does not accept payments of this type. (401) | PayPal
>   Debug-ID: 6e5e3e819f7c4

**SOLVED!**
 I CREATED A NEW APP IN THE PAYPAL APPLICATIONS AND HAS WORKED!